# fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 in react native Android

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I am using fetch for a **"https"** GET request it **works fine in IOS** but throws **SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0** error in android. when i checked the status it was **" status 401 "**, i even checked the grade of my domain its "A" grade.

this is my build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

my react and react native versions are below

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4"
```

I even tried to add the below code in my AndroidManifes.xml file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"
```

I tried everything but i dont exactly know what's the issue, Please help thanks.

Comment: can you share me what you are sending as the api url and any body params

Comment: fetch('API')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log("response", responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

Comment: inside fetch('API') what are you passing as API? is it just API string?

Comment: @GauravRoy i cannot send you the API as its confidential its something like this

    https://xyz%40gmail.com:password@domain.name.com/rest/items

Comment: there is some problem with api i guess, have you tried using in postman? does it work there>?

Comment: yes it works in postman and even in IOS.

Comment: the same works in ios with fetch?

Comment: yes its woking in ios @GauravRoy